# Regex to strip span inside a tag using classic ASP

Tags: regex, asp-classic

I would like to strip `<span>` tags and their styles from within `<h2>` tags eg

```
<h2><span style="font-family: sans-serif;">{text to remain}</span></h2>
```

or

```
<h2><span style="font-family:font-size: 26.3158px;">{text to remain}</span></h2>
```

would become

```
<h2>{text to remain}</h2>
```

Any suggestions of how to achieve this with regex? Ideally in classic ASP (don't ask).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got there in the end:

```
objRegExp.Pattern = "(<h2(.*?)>)(<span(.*?)>)(.*?)(<\/span>)(<\/h2>)"
vartext = objRegExp.Replace(vartext, "$1$5$7")
```

Answer (score 0):

I whipped this out pretty quick, so it may have some issues, but it worked. You will need to update it for double quotes.

```
<%

text = "<h2><span style='font-family:font-size: 26.3158px;'>{text to remain}</span></h2>"

dim objRegExp : set objRegExp = new RegExp
objRegExp.Pattern = "<\/?span(\ style='.*')?>"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
cleanText = objRegExp.replace(text, "")


response.write text
response.write cleanText

%>
```

Results:

```
<h2><span style='font-family:font-size: 26.3158px;'>{text to remain}</span></h2>
<h2>{text to remain}</h2>
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks. So pleased. Is there a way of restricting it so that it only targets spans in `h2`s?

Comment: With regex, you can really select almost anything. You should go to a site like https://regex101.com/ that will allow you to play with the regex to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCollins . I've had a play on regex101.com - never realised there were so many possibilities! Just can't figure out how to restrict it to spans inside h2s. I obviously need more coffee. Is there any way you could help a confused Londoner out here?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how to use ASP, but I'll take a stab and guess that it uses the same regex rules as JavaScript and hope that this might help you:

```js
var str =
    '<h2><span style="font-family: sans-serif;">{text to remain}</span></h2>';

// I put the no-regex version so you can see the difference in the output.
document.write(str);
document.write(str.replace(/<\/?\s*span[^>]*>/, ''));
```

Bear in mind that this is a very simple implementation and will fail in a case like: `<span data-text="woah>asd">`. In an ideal world, that'd be written `woah&gt;asd` and thus not be a problem, but HTML isn't always valid.